# Ant, apply task debug

Tags: debugging, ant

Migrating from ant to gradle, I'd like to inspect the total arguments passed along while linking native code [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/config/linux/build.xml#L123-L138):

```
        <apply executable="${gcc}" failonerror="true" parallel="true" taskname="Linker" unless:set="lib-uptodate">
            <srcfile/>
            <arg value="-shared"/>
            <arg value="-m64" if:set="build.arch.x64"/>
            <arg value="-m32" if:set="build.arch.x86"/>

            <arg line="-z noexecstack"/>
            <arg line="-O3 -flto -fPIC -pthread -o ${lib.arch}/lib${name}.so"/>

            <arg line="-Wl,--no-undefined"/>
            <arg line="-Wl,--version-script,${version.script}"/>
            <arg line="-Wl,--wrap,memcpy" if:set="build.arch.x64"/>
            <fileset dir="${bin.native}" includes="wrap_memcpy.o" if:set="build.arch.x64"/>
            <fileset dir="${dest}" includes="*.o"/>
            <link/>
        </apply>
```

however, it worked in the past days, now the output is quite concise

```
[gcc] Linking lwjgl
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/libs/native/linux/x64/org/lwjgl
[Linker] Applied gcc to 21 files and 0 directories.
```

But if I add

```
<record name="build.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
... apply "linking"
<record name="build.log" action="stop"/>
```

Then I see under `build.log` the log I was used to see

```
   [Linker] Current OS is Linux
   [Linker] Executing 'gcc' with arguments:
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/wrap_memcpy.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/common_tools.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_Callback.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_JNI.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_MemoryAccessJNI.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_MemoryUtil.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_ThreadLocalUtil.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_dyncall_DynCall.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_dyncall_DynCallback.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_dyncall_DynLoad.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_jawt_JAWTFunctions.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_jni_JNINativeInterface.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_libc_LibCErrno.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_libc_LibCLocale.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_libc_LibCStdio.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_libc_LibCStdlib.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_libc_LibCString.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/linux/x64/core/org_lwjgl_system_linux_DynamicLinkLoader.o'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/libs/native/linux/x64/org/lwjgl/libdyncall_s.a'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/libs/native/linux/x64/org/lwjgl/libdyncallback_s.a'
'/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/bin/libs/native/linux/x64/org/lwjgl/libdynload_s.a'
'-shared'
'-m64'
'-z'
'noexecstack'
'-O3'
'-flto'
'-fPIC'
'-pthread'
'-o'
'bin/libs/native/linux/x64/org/lwjgl/liblwjgl.so'
'-Wl,--no-undefined'
'-Wl,--version-script,/home/elect/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3/config/linux/version.script'
'-Wl,--wrap,memcpy'
'-ldl'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
   [Linker] Applied gcc to 21 files and 0 directories.
```

But I cant wrap my head around why it's not working anymore with
`ant -v > out.txt`

I even re-cloned the project to try again, but nothing

How may I solve?

Specs:

```
elect@5800x:~/IdeaProjects/lwjgl3$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on January 8 1970
```

Comment: Which Ant version is it?

Comment: @martinclayton question updated

Comment: Verbose mode works for me with the 1.10.8 binary download.  Looks like yours was built from source on a machine with an odd date.  Could it be that Ant has been rebuilt locally since it last worked for you?

Comment: I removed with `sudo apt purge ant` and reinstalled it again with `sudo apt install ant`.. very same compilation date. How did you install yours? Are you on Linux?

Comment: I downloaded Ant from the apache site - you could try that, see if you still have the issue with a build from there.